# How do I fix "Body Parameters Accepted in Query"?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Recently my project gone through yearly scan and some Vulnerabilities were found 
one of these is **Body Parameters Accepted in Query** I have searched a lot but could not found any solution for this.
Can any one please help me with it.

Below is some Scanned PDF content for the site/Project

```
    GET /?  
       __LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=&__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&txtUsername=&txtPassword=&btnLogin=Login HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko 
Referer: https://xxx.xxxxx.com/ 
    Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=yszj4dpu2hv1gwr4ulx0zhfy 
    Connection: keep-alive
```

I am not sure about solution?
According to PDF Solution is given 
**Fix: Do not accept body parameters that are sent in the query string**
????

Comment: This is not vulnerability if you not pass this parameters as string to some sql query - and you can not know if the page is actually accept them - probably is not accept them and the test just dont understand it - its not accept it if no `__EVENTVALIDATION` exist there - I supose that you run asp.net forms

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply and suggestion.I Got it solved I was getting values in `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EventValidation` hidden tag in the source code of login form

so I ADDED the code in .aspx

```
enableEventValidation="false" EnableViewState="false"
```

And In .aspx.cs

```
 protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object state)
        {
            //base.SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(state);
        }
        protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
        {
            return null; //return base.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium();
        }
        protected override object SaveViewState()
        {
            return null;// base.SaveViewState();
        }
```

and on click button I ADDED `OnClientClick` attribute in the `<asp:Button onClientClick` calles client side function before the click of `Onclick`.

These things some how solved the problem of **Body Parameters Accepted in Query** In My case.

Thanks for the help!!