# Body Parameters Accepted in Query(ASP.Net C# webform)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Recently my project gone through yearly scan and some Vulnerabilities were found one of these is Body Parameters Accepted in Query I have searched a lot but could not found any solution for this. Can any one please help me with it.

**PDF content**

**Severity:** Low

**CVSS Score:** 5.0

**Entity:** consumerVerification.aspx (Page)

**Risk: **It is possible to gather sensitive information about the web application such as usernames,
passwords, machine name and/or sensitive file locations
It is possible to persuade a naive user to supply sensitive information such as username, password,
credit card number, social security number etc.

**Causes:** Insecure web application programming or configuration

**Fix:** Do not accept body parameters that are sent in the query string

**Difference:**
**Body Parameter removed from request: **
AYPKelFSQ9gGuhF7gzR8deB8IN9Frp1nPhffwZVPguZkZjquYByIDrX3XA91fZJ7Nqbf9Jk+lAiJ+60b/XOPsi/m
nMq75scGQ1f2QOWNLvQ=
**Query Parameter added to request: **
AYPKelFSQ9gGuhF7gzR8deB8IN9Frp1nPhffwZVPguZkZjquYByIDrX3XA91fZJ7Nqbf9Jk+lAiJ+60b/XOPsi/m
nMq75scGQ1f2QOWNLvQ=
**Body Parameter removed from request:** 03F61B3A Query Parameter added to request: 03F61B3A Body **Parameter removed from request: **
**Query Parameter added to request: **
**Method manipulated from: **POST to: GET

**Reasoning:** The test result seems to indicate a vulnerability because the Test Response is similar to
the Original Response, indicating that the application processed body parameters that were
submitted in the query

**PDF content**

**General**
Re-program the application to disallow handling of POST parameters that were listed in the Query

**note:** i'm not using mvc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62088949/how-do-i-fix-body-parameters-accepted-in-query